# How do you list a property on a string and set a default value, Error = #1069

Tags: flash

I can't do this the textbook is outdated and my teacher knows nothing, being the bum he is.

Tried as much as i know.

```
var hits: Number = 0;

runIT.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK);

function runIT(event: MouseEvent) 

{
    var heartInstance: targetMC = new targetMC

    addChild(heartInstance).x = 260(heartInstance).y = 220;

}
```

I expected the button to work but the output is

> ReferenceError: Error #1069: Property addEventListener not found on builtin.as$0.MethodClosure and there is no default value.
>       at skillsDemo10_Scene1_fla::MainTimeline/frame1()

Answer (score 1):

Try importing Events at the top of your code:

```
import flash.events.Event;
```

Also [**`addChild`**](https://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/states/AddChild.html) function/method does **not** have an `.x` or `.y` property, so commands like  `addChild(heartInstance).x` should give errors too.

Whenever you `addChild` an object that has some on-screen `.x` and `.y` position, that object will be  **class**ed as a [**Display Object** (*read about it in the AS3 manual*)](https://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObject.html).

Compare your own...

```
var heartInstance: targetMC = new targetMC
addChild(heartInstance).x = 260(heartInstance).y = 220;
```

With this *modified* setup from the manual...

```
var square :SomeThing = new SomeThing();
square.x = 150;
square.y = 150;
addChild(square);
```

Fixes:

1) A new instance of a class requires `();` (to show that it's a Class)...

```
var heartInstance: targetMC = new targetMC();
```

2) You shouldn't use like: `addChild(heartInstance).x = 260(heartInstance).y = 220;`

the correct setup:

```
heartInstance.x = 260;
heartInstance.y = 220;
addChild(heartInstance);
```

Comment: Actually, **addChild(...)** method returns the same display object it is given, so **addChild(...).x = 100** line is not entirely incorrect, just weird and confusing: https://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObjectContainer.html#addChild() The style you provided in your answer is much better, of course.